Real Structure in a Calabi-Yau Manifold
I'm studying examples of special Lagrangian submanifold in a Calabi-Yau manifold. The definition of a Calabi-Yau manifold that I'm following is:
Let $M$ be a $n$ dimensional manifold, $\omega$ a Kähler form and the real and the imaginary parts $\Omega_{1}$ and $\Omega_{2}$ of the covariant constant $n$ form. If we have:

$\omega$ is non-degenerate.
$\Omega_{1}+i\Omega_{2}$ is locally decomposable non-vanishing.
$\Omega_{1} \wedge \omega = \Omega_{2} \wedge \omega = 0$.
$(\Omega_{1}+i\Omega_{2})\wedge (\Omega_{1}-i\Omega_{2}) = \omega^{n}$ (respect. $i\omega^{n}$) if $n$ is even (respect. odd).
$d\omega = 0$, $d\Omega_{1} = 0$ and $d\Omega_{2}=0$

Then $M$ is a Calabi-Yau manifold.
The article claims that a real structure in a Calabi-Yau manifold is equivalent to consider an antiholomorphic involution $\sigma$ for which $\sigma ^{*} \omega = -\omega$ and $\sigma^{*} \Omega_{2} = -\Omega_{2}$.
First of all, what is the right definition of a real complex structure for a manifold? and how can I get the equivalence he claims?
The only definition that I found just says what is a real structure for complex vector spaces.

A real structure on a complex manifold is a smoothly varying real structure on the fibres of its holomorphic tangent bundle.

Thanks for you answer! But I really don't get it why $(d\sigma)_{p}$ is a real structure on the fibres.

I have somewhat ideosyncratic notation: let $X$ be a smooth manifold, and let $\mathcal{X}$ denote the pair $(X,J)$ of the smooth manifold together with an equivalence class of integrable complex structures $J$. That is to say, $\mathcal{X}$ denotes the manifold together with its complex structure up to isomorphism.
Let's say that $(\mathcal{X},\omega)$ is a Kähler manifold, and that $\Omega\in H^0(X,\Omega_\mathcal{X}^n)$ makes it into a Calabi-Yau manifold. Then $\Omega$ defines a map $TX\otimes\mathbb{C}\to\wedge^{n-1}T^*X\otimes\mathbb{C}$ by interior multiplication. Its kernel is $T\mathcal{X}^{0,1}$, the anti-holomorphic tangent bundle. Now if $\Omega=\Omega_1+i\Omega_2$, and $\sigma:X\to X$ is such that $\sigma^*\Omega_2=-\Omega_2$ and $\sigma^*\omega=-\omega$, then you can use the relations between $\Omega$ and $\omega$ you wrote down above to deduce how $T\mathcal{X}^{0,1}$ (and therefore also $T\mathcal{X}^{1,0}$) behaves under $\sigma$. That part, I'll leave for you to figure out. But I hope the road to get there is clear.
